# Url rewrite does not match site root

Tags: asp.net, regex, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404

I 'm using Intelligencia.UrlRewriter in my ASP.NET web application.

My code is like :

```
<rewrite url="~/article/(.+)" to="~/$1" />
```

I want to redirect all files with url like **www.mysite.com/article/foooo** be redirected to **www.mysite.com/foooo** .

but strangely pages like  **www.mysite.com/something/Images/article/1.jpg** will redirect to **www.mysite.com/1.jpg** so I get page not found error(404) .

what is the problem ? is the sign (~) matches the site url(root)  ?

Comment: Is that the only rewrite rule?

Comment: no there are no other rules

Comment: Maybe try using something like `<rewrite url="^(.+?/)article/(.+)" to="$1$2" />` instead since `~` doesn't seem to behave as expected.

Comment: thanks thats fix that, put it on answers plz